# Why is Cordova's config.xml read-only by default?

Tags: cordova

Are there things that we should be careful about when overriding config.xml?

After it is generated by `cordova create`, why is it read-only by default?
We would most probably need to configure the file manually am I right?

Comment: Which operating system and version of Cordova are you using?  I don't see this with Cordova 6.5.0 on Mac OS X where config.xml is created with -rw-r--r-- permissions.  Also, this could be a feature of your user's umask setting?  My umask is set to 0022.

Comment: I use the latest Mac OS X (10.12.13) and Cordova 6.5.0 as well. I've never touched anything related to umask. First time I've heard of umask haha. My machine is a brand new Touch Bar 15".

Comment: Try typing umask into terminal and see what output you get I am thinking your account might be set to create files read only.

Comment: 0022 hrm... odd

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be read-only. You're expected to edit it to set the application name, permissions, author, icons, splash screen images, and more. There are even Cordova CLI commands like:

```
cordova platform --save
```

and

```
cordova plugin --save
```

That write to the file (saving the platforms list and plugins list respectively). These commands will (should) fail if the file is read-only.

So, to answer your first question: No, nothing to be careful of, adjust the file's contents as needed for your app.